# Significance of angle in relativistic mass equation

Tags: special-relativity, mass, relativity

I was playing with 
$$M=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$
and when I put $v=c\sin\theta$, I got 
$$M=m_0\sec\theta.$$
And this new equation is appearing so beautiful and attracting to me that I was compelled to think whether $\theta$ appearing here has any physical significance or it is just a mathematical artifact? Whether it is directing to somewhere? Can you please help me?

N.B. Here by "directing to somewhere" I mean similar to the following one

In the conversion of Coulomb's law to Gauss law it was $r^2$ directing us towards surface area and eventually to Flux concept.

Comment: You could be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity .

Answer (score 1):

There is geometrical significance.   You are sooo close.  You are in Euclidean space, but you should be in hyperbolic space.

As @fqq points out, you have stumbled upon *rapidity*, a parameter in hyperbolic geometry that is the analog of *angle* in Euclidean geometry.

In Euclidean geometry an angle (in radians) is a parameter that measures the Euclidean length of arcs on a unit circle.  For example, the length of an arc of a unit circle subtended by an angle of $\pi$ radians is $\pi$.

Rapidity measures *invariant interval* between two events on a unit hyperbola.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity) has lots of information, but I don't see the geometrical interpretation there.